# I want to show top 5 from an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, fetch-api

Screenshot of the `console.log`：

[image]

I want to choose the top five objects from the below array of objects it's not working. To choose 5 elements I have applied `slice()` but it's not working. When I console the result it shows me all the elements it has.  Please help me doing this.  Below is my code:

```
 async function getCoins() {
    let url = 'https://bitbns.com/order/getTopTickerVolume/';
    try {
      let res = await fetch(url);
      return await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  async function renderCurrency() {
    let currencies = await getCoins();
    //console.log(currencies,'JSHR')
    let html = '';
    var coinlist = [];
    
    coinlist.push(currencies);
    console.log(coinlist);
    const fiveValues = coinlist.slice(0, 5);

    console.log(fiveValues,"five")
    
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(coinlist)) {      
      for (const [key1, value1] of Object.entries(value)) {
        //console.log(value1,"hello")
        

        var diff = value1.last_traded_price-value1.highest_buy_bid;
        var change = diff.toFixed(2);
        let htmlSegment = `<tr>
                              <td><img src="bitcoin.png">${key1}/INR</td>
                              <td>${value1.highest_buy_bid}</td>
                              <td>${change}</td>
                          </tr>`;
      html += htmlSegment;

      }
    }


    let banner = document.querySelector('#tablebody');
    banner.innerHTML = html;

  }

  renderCurrency();
</script>
```

and here is the console log result that I get:

```
[
    {
        "BTC": {
            "highest_buy_bid": 2627674.07,
            "lowest_sell_bid": 2635150,
            "last_traded_price": 2619002.02,
            "volume": {
                "max": "2662220.89",
                "min": "2275000.00",
                "volume": 126.32525071
            }
        },
        "ETH": {
            "highest_buy_bid": 155291.33,
            "lowest_sell_bid": 155800,
            "last_traded_price": 155789.27,
            "volume": {
                "max": "157995.43",
                "min": "134430.00",
                "volume": 1477.4024985
            }
        },
        "XRP": {
            "highest_buy_bid": 46.8,
            "lowest_sell_bid": 47,
            "last_traded_price": 47,
            "volume": {
                "max": "49.37",
                "min": "40.16",
                "volume": 1974895.82
            }
        },
        "BNS": {
            "highest_buy_bid": 5.38,
            "lowest_sell_bid": 5.43,
            "last_traded_price": 5.37,
            "volume": {
                "max": "5.49",
                "min": "5.22",
                "volume": 933417.9355
            }
        },
        "DOGE": {
            "highest_buy_bid": 16.183,
            "lowest_sell_bid": 16.265,
            "last_traded_price": 16.265,
            "volume": {
                "max": "17.259",
                "min": "12.967",
                "volume": 8058176
            }
        },
        "ADA": {
            "highest_buy_bid": 96.68,
            "lowest_sell_bid": 96.69,
            "last_traded_price": 96.68,
            "volume": {
                "max": "97.99",
                "min": "79.00",
                "volume": 3043873.8
            }
        },
        "DOT": {
            "highest_buy_bid": 1240,
            "lowest_sell_bid": 1247.02,
            "last_traded_price": 1247.41,
            "volume": {
                "max": "1288.28",
                "min": "1027.33",
                "volume": 39325.4208
            }
        },
        "AAVE": {
            "highest_buy_bid": 17245.38,
            "lowest_sell_bid": 17389.92,
            "last_traded_price": 17201.18,
            "volume": {
                "max": "17469.80",
                "min": "13496.90",
                "volume": 979.43
            }
        },
        "BNB": {
            "highest_buy_bid": 22100.31,
            "lowest_sell_bid": 22256.47,
            "last_traded_price": 22336.93,
            "volume": {
                "max": "22705.08",
                "min": "18051.97",
                "volume": 6377.23
            }
        },
        "SOL": {
            "highest_buy_bid": 2299.08,
            "lowest_sell_bid": 2319,
            "last_traded_price": 2294.67,
            "volume": {
                "max": "2421.79",
                "min": "1610.00",
                "volume": 21862.1351
            }
        },
        "MATIC": {
            "highest_buy_bid": 91.596,
            "lowest_sell_bid": 91.6,
            "last_traded_price": 91.6,
            "volume": {
                "max": "95.550",
                "min": "73.380",
                "volume": 714962
            }
        },
        "UNI": {
            "highest_buy_bid": 1372.81,
            "lowest_sell_bid": 1386.59,
            "last_traded_price": 1396.46,
            "volume": {
                "max": "1414.69",
                "min": "1093.00",
                "volume": 1235.39
            }
        },
        "CRV": {
            "highest_buy_bid": 117.15,
            "lowest_sell_bid": 118.52,
            "last_traded_price": 116.61,
            "volume": {
                "max": "120.50",
                "min": "96.35",
                "volume": 367729.311
            }
        },
        "YFI": {
            "highest_buy_bid": 2429207.42,
            "lowest_sell_bid": 2453040.98,
            "last_traded_price": 2428926.85,
            "volume": {
                "max": "2491352.60",
                "min": "1971910.23",
                "volume": 7.209645
            }
        },
        "CAKE": {
            "highest_buy_bid": 1016.69,
            "lowest_sell_bid": 1026.83,
            "last_traded_price": 1016.69,
            "volume": {
                "max": "1047.52",
                "min": "757.68",
                "volume": 25417.21
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: `coinlist` only has one element after `coinlist.push(currencies)`. How do you expect to slice 5 elements from that?

Comment: You have an array with one object in it. What is the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Your returned object is an array but it has only one element. Notice [{ anyObject}].

Comment: The object has 15 properties. Are you trying to get 5 of those properties?

Comment: Convert it into an array first and you are good to go.

Comment: try it: `x = your array/object` and then use `x.splice(0,4)` also learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `currencies` object to an array with `Object.entries()`. Then you can sort it and slice the first five of these.

```js
async function renderCurrency() {
  let currencies = await getCoins();
  //console.log(currencies,'JSHR')
  let html = '';
  var coinlist = Object.entries(currencies).sort((c1, c2) => c1[1].highest_buy_bid - c2[1].highest_buy_bid).slice(0, 5);

  console.log(coinlist);

  for (const [key, value] of coinlist) {
    var diff = value.last_traded_price - value.highest_buy_bid;
    var change = diff.toFixed(2);
    let htmlSegment = `<tr>
                          <td><img src="bitcoin.png">${key1}/INR</td>
                          <td>${value.highest_buy_bid}</td>
                          <td>${change}</td>
                       </tr>`;
    html += htmlSegment;
  }

  let banner = document.querySelector('#tablebody');
  banner.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @barmar for the reply. But what I want here is the top 5 sorting the highest_buy_bid. Can you please just tell me that?

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the `Object.entries` and use `slice` to get the top 5. Then create a new object from those entries with `Object.fromEntries`.

```js
const data = [{
  "BTC": {
    "highest_buy_bid": 2627674.07,
    "lowest_sell_bid": 2635150,
    "last_traded_price": 2619002.02,
    "volume": {
      "max": "2662220.89",
      "min": "2275000.00",
      "volume": 126.32525071
    }
  },
  "ETH": {
    "highest_buy_bid": 155291.33,
    "lowest_sell_bid": 155800,
    "last_traded_price": 155789.27,
    "volume": {
      "max": "157995.43",
      "min": "134430.00",
      "volume": 1477.4024985
    }
  },
  "XRP": {
    "highest_buy_bid": 46.8,
    "lowest_sell_bid": 47,
    "last_traded_price": 47,
    "volume": {
      "max": "49.37",
      "min": "40.16",
      "volume": 1974895.82
    }
  },
  "BNS": {
    "highest_buy_bid": 5.38,
    "lowest_sell_bid": 5.43,
    "last_traded_price": 5.37,
    "volume": {
      "max": "5.49",
      "min": "5.22",
      "volume": 933417.9355
    }
  },
  "DOGE": {
    "highest_buy_bid": 16.183,
    "lowest_sell_bid": 16.265,
    "last_traded_price": 16.265,
    "volume": {
      "max": "17.259",
      "min": "12.967",
      "volume": 8058176
    }
  },
  "ADA": {
    "highest_buy_bid": 96.68,
    "lowest_sell_bid": 96.69,
    "last_traded_price": 96.68,
    "volume": {
      "max": "97.99",
      "min": "79.00",
      "volume": 3043873.8
    }
  },
  "DOT": {
    "highest_buy_bid": 1240,
    "lowest_sell_bid": 1247.02,
    "last_traded_price": 1247.41,
    "volume": {
      "max": "1288.28",
      "min": "1027.33",
      "volume": 39325.4208
    }
  },
  "AAVE": {
    "highest_buy_bid": 17245.38,
    "lowest_sell_bid": 17389.92,
    "last_traded_price": 17201.18,
    "volume": {
      "max": "17469.80",
      "min": "13496.90",
      "volume": 979.43
    }
  },
  "BNB": {
    "highest_buy_bid": 22100.31,
    "lowest_sell_bid": 22256.47,
    "last_traded_price": 22336.93,
    "volume": {
      "max": "22705.08",
      "min": "18051.97",
      "volume": 6377.23
    }
  },
  "SOL": {
    "highest_buy_bid": 2299.08,
    "lowest_sell_bid": 2319,
    "last_traded_price": 2294.67,
    "volume": {
      "max": "2421.79",
      "min": "1610.00",
      "volume": 21862.1351
    }
  },
  "MATIC": {
    "highest_buy_bid": 91.596,
    "lowest_sell_bid": 91.6,
    "last_traded_price": 91.6,
    "volume": {
      "max": "95.550",
      "min": "73.380",
      "volume": 714962
    }
  },
  "UNI": {
    "highest_buy_bid": 1372.81,
    "lowest_sell_bid": 1386.59,
    "last_traded_price": 1396.46,
    "volume": {
      "max": "1414.69",
      "min": "1093.00",
      "volume": 1235.39
    }
  },
  "CRV": {
    "highest_buy_bid": 117.15,
    "lowest_sell_bid": 118.52,
    "last_traded_price": 116.61,
    "volume": {
      "max": "120.50",
      "min": "96.35",
      "volume": 367729.311
    }
  },
  "YFI": {
    "highest_buy_bid": 2429207.42,
    "lowest_sell_bid": 2453040.98,
    "last_traded_price": 2428926.85,
    "volume": {
      "max": "2491352.60",
      "min": "1971910.23",
      "volume": 7.209645
    }
  },
  "CAKE": {
    "highest_buy_bid": 1016.69,
    "lowest_sell_bid": 1026.83,
    "last_traded_price": 1016.69,
    "volume": {
      "max": "1047.52",
      "min": "757.68",
      "volume": 25417.21
    }
  }
}]

// sort entries by highest buy order
const sortedEntries = Object.entries(data[0]).sort(([, va], [, vb]) => {
  return vb.highest_buy_bid - va.highest_buy_bid;
});

// create new object from first 5 sorted entries
const result = Object.fromEntries(sortedEntries.slice(0, 5));

console.log(result);
```